# Two CTEs and a UNION ALL to compare datasets results in unexpected results

Tags: sum, common-table-expression, partition, union-all, cross-apply

Two CTEs were written to return results sets from different select statements.  A UNION ALL of the result sets ends with the number of differences between the two cte's changing each time it is executed.

I've commented out some lines of the script and it appears that the issue is related to UNION ALL of the result sets for columns 'Premium', 'Taxes', 'TimeSpanID'.  Is there a different method that can be used to compare the results of the script below:

```
WITH
CTE1 AS (
select [TransactionDateID]
  ,[TransactionTypeID]
  ,[TransactionID]
  ,[BillingAccountID]
  ,[BillingInvoiceID]
  ,[BillingPaymentID]
  ,[Premium]
  ,[Taxes]
  ,[TimeSpanID]
  from Fact.SalesBalance1
) ,
CTE2 AS(
SELECT TransactionDateID=MAX(TransactionDateID) OVER (PARTITION BY 
[BillingAccountID] ORDER BY [StartDate]),
TransactionTypeID,
TransactionID,
BillingAccountID,
BillingInvoiceID,
BillingPaymentID,
Premium=SUM(Premium) OVER (PARTITION BY [BillingAccountID] ORDER BY 
StartDate),
Taxes=SUM(Taxes) OVER (PARTITION BY [BillingAccountID] ORDER BY StartDate),
TimeSpanID
FROM 
(
    SELECT *,

    StartDate=[DateKey],

    EndDate=ISNULL(MAX([DateKey]) OVER (PARTITION BY [BillingAccountID] 
ORDER BY DateKey ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING),
CAST('12/31/9999' AS DATE))
    FROM Fact.SalesTransaction P
    INNER JOIN Dim.SalesTransDate Q ON P.TransactionDateID = 
Q.CalendarDateID
) T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TimeSpanID FROM Dim.TimeSpan WHERE StartDate = T.StartDate AND 
EndDate = T.EndDate
)TS  

)

SELECT MIN(TableName) as TableName
, TransactionDateID
,TransactionTypeID
,TransactionID
,BillingAccountID
,BillingInvoiceID
,BillingPaymentID
,Premium
,Taxes
,TimeSpanID
FROM
(
SELECT 'Fact CTE1' as TableName
, A.TransactionDateID
,A.TransactionTypeID
,A.TransactionID
,A.BillingAccountID
,A.BillingInvoiceID
,A.BillingPaymentID
,A.Premium
,A.Taxes
,A.TimeSpanID
FROM CTE1 A
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fact CTE2’ as TableName, B.TransactionDateID
,B.TransactionTypeID
,B.TransactionID
,B.BillingAccountID
,B.BillingInvoiceID
,B.BillingPaymentID
,B.Premium
,B.Taxes
,B.TimeSpanID
FROM CTE2 B
) tmp

GROUP BY TransactionDateID
,TransactionTypeID
,TransactionID
,BillingAccountID
,BillingInvoiceID
,BillingPaymentID
,Premium
,Taxes
,TimeSpanID
HAVING COUNT(0) = 1
ORDER BY TransactionDateID
,TransactionTypeID
,TransactionID
,BillingAccountID
,BillingInvoiceID
,BillingPaymentID
,TimeSpanID
```

Comment: When I comment out 'UNION ALL' in the comparison of the two results sets and use 'INTERSECT', it works:

Answer (score 0):

It appears that UNION ALL doesn't play nice in my question.  I changed 'UNION ALL' to 'INTERSECT' per the updated script below and it worked:

```
WITH
CTE1 AS (
select [TransactionDateID]
  ,[TransactionTypeID]
  ,[TransactionID]
  ,[BillingAccountID]
  ,[BillingInvoiceID]
  ,[BillingPaymentID]
  ,[Premium]
  ,[Taxes]
  ,[TimeSpanID]
  from Fact.SalesBalance1
) ,
CTE2 AS(
SELECT TransactionDateID=MAX(TransactionDateID) OVER (PARTITION BY 
[BillingAccountID] ORDER BY [StartDate]),
TransactionTypeID,
TransactionID,
BillingAccountID,
BillingInvoiceID,
BillingPaymentID,
Premium=SUM(Premium) OVER (PARTITION BY [BillingAccountID] ORDER BY 
StartDate),
Taxes=SUM(Taxes) OVER (PARTITION BY [BillingAccountID] ORDER BY StartDate),
TimeSpanID
FROM 

(
    SELECT *,

    StartDate=[DateKey],

    EndDate=ISNULL(MAX([DateKey]) OVER (PARTITION BY [BillingAccountID] 
ORDER BY DateKey ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING),
CAST('12/31/9999' AS DATE))
    FROM Fact.SalesTransaction P
    INNER JOIN Dim.SalesTransDate Q ON P.TransactionDateID = 
Q.CalendarDateID
) T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TimeSpanID FROM Dim.TimeSpan WHERE StartDate = T.StartDate AND 
EndDate = T.EndDate
)TS  

)

SELECT MIN(TableName) as TableName
, TransactionDateID
,TransactionTypeID
,TransactionID
,BillingAccountID
,BillingInvoiceID
,BillingPaymentID
,Premium
,Taxes
,TimeSpanID
FROM

(
SELECT 'Fact CTE1' as TableName
, A.TransactionDateID
,A.TransactionTypeID
,A.TransactionID
,A.BillingAccountID
,A.BillingInvoiceID
,A.BillingPaymentID
,A.Premium
,A.Taxes
,A.TimeSpanID
FROM CTE1 A
INTERSECT
--UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fact CTE2’ as TableName, B.TransactionDateID
,B.TransactionTypeID
,B.TransactionID
,B.BillingAccountID
,B.BillingInvoiceID
,B.BillingPaymentID
,B.Premium
,B.Taxes
,B.TimeSpanID
```

FROM CTE2 B
) tmp

GROUP BY TransactionDateID
    ,TransactionTypeID
    ,TransactionID
    ,BillingAccountID
    ,BillingInvoiceID
    ,BillingPaymentID
    ,Premium
    ,Taxes
    ,TimeSpanID
    HAVING COUNT(0) = 1
    ORDER BY TransactionDateID
    ,TransactionTypeID
    ,TransactionID
    ,BillingAccountID
    ,BillingInvoiceID
    ,BillingPaymentID
    ,TimeSpanID

Comment: It appeared that this worked, but changing from a UNION ALL to INTERSECT didn't work.